# Java Object.wait(long) how does it wake up itself?

Tags: java, thread-safety

example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        for (; ; ) {
            System.out.println("每5秒打印一次");
            lock.wait(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Just a single-thread loop waits for a few seconds and wakes up to print information, no other threads call notify, how does it automatically wake up itself?

Comment: Because you've specified a 5 second timeout? Or are you asking about the inner workings of the mechanism?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the underlying principle. As far as I know, the waiting thread should only be awakened by other threads calling notify, but there is no other thread to wake it up at all.

Comment: Well I don't know the underlying principle. However this is not true like I said in my other comment: *the waiting thread should only be awakened by other threads calling notify, but there is no other thread to wake it up at all.*

Answer (score 2):

What did you think the `5000` means there?

`lock.wait(5000)` means: Start a timer and wait until the **first** of any of these 3 things occurs:

- If 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds) pass, exit this method normally.
- If someone calls `notifyAll()` (or notify) on the same object `lock` is referencing, exit this method normally.
- If someone calls `.interrupt()` on this thread, exit by way of throwing InterruptedException.

So, if nobody is invoking notify, then this will wait 5 seconds. It's just a silly way of writing `Thread.sleep(5000)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am curious how the waiting thread can resume running without other threads notify. Now it seems that the operating system thread scheduling task polls to check whether the waiting time of the thread has timed out. If it times out, Run this thread, when the timeout is set to 0, it will never time out, and can only wait for other threads to notify? I don't understand how the operating system schedules threads, so I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

There's a scheduler whose job it is to run threads.  The scheduler knows about threads and whether they are currently runnable. It presumably has a queue of objects waiting on timer expiration.  Those threads are not runnable 'now' but they become runnable when their time is up.

This is the same principle as in most operating systems. Execute a 'sleep for N seconds' system call. Something exists that will make the thread runnable again.

Comment: What you mean is that it is determined by the thread scheduler of the operating system. The scheduler will cyclically  check whether the wait time has expired. If there is no timeout, it will continue to wait. If it has expired, it will occupy the cpu time slice?

Comment: Might be the OS's scheduler if it has one, might be something in the JVM even if the OS has a scheduler, it doesn't really matter. If I had to implement this on a system without threads, then I'd have "something" that was getting executed on a timer, plus queues of blocked and runnable threads. Timer expiration moves a thread from blocked to runnable; executing wait moves it from runnable to blocked.  "Something else" picks a thread off the head of the runnable queue and transfers control to it.